# IndexError: list index out of range while loop thru entire directory

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to loop thru list of files and add some additional information in each column. Following code snippet works fine for one file but if I have many files that does not work.

Code:

```
def list_csv_files(csv_folder):
    input_file_list = []    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".csv"):
                input_file_list.append(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, name)))
                print input_file_list
                with open(input_file, 'rb') as f, open(temp_file, 'w') as fo: #PROBLEM HERE
                    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
                    for row in reader:
                        one = '"'+ row[0] + '"'
                        two = row[1]
                        three = '"'+ row[2] +'"'
                        print >> fo, one,two,three
                    os.rename(temp_file, input_file)
list_csv_files(csv_folder)
```

**Input File1 : foo.csv**

```
ProjectB - TIM - 2619,2,4/11/07
ProjectB - TIM - 2504,2,9/19/06
ProjectB - TIM - 2374,2,4/7/06
ProjectB - TIM - 2373,2,4/7/06
ProjectB - TIM - 2284,2,2/21/06
```

**Input File2: bar.csv**

```
ProjectC - TIM - 2619,2,4/11/07
ProjectC - TIM - 2504,2,9/19/06
```

**Expected Output File1: foo.csv**

```
"ProjectB - TIM - 2619" 2 "4/11/07"
"ProjectB - TIM - 2504" 2 "9/19/06"
"ProjectB - TIM - 2374" 2 "4/7/06"
"ProjectB - TIM - 2373" 2 "4/7/06"
"ProjectB - TIM - 2284" 2 "2/21/06"
```

**Expected Output File2: bar.csv**

```
"ProjectC - TIM - 2619" 2 "4/11/07"
"ProjectC - TIM - 2504" 2 "9/19/06"
```

**Error** -   I get error index out of error, since can not loop thru all files.

```
File "read_csv.py", line 143, in <module>
    two = row[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: There is some line which does not have any `,` at all, maybe an empty line, did you check that?

Comment: is you input output the exact input output you are getting??

Comment: please show one file that does not work!

Comment: @AnandSKumar Since it is a CSV file delimiter is only , and each column are separated with `,` . All the input files have `,`

Comment: @Ymartin If I have only one file in the directory that works fine, but if I have multiple file e.g. foo.csv and bar.csv in the same directory then it does not work

Comment: @Roujri show the content of one csv file that doesnt work

Comment: @bigOTHER Input File2: bar.csv is the content of the file. To reproduce the problem I put sample input files. The problem is loop thru the files it does not get the next file

Comment: @AnandSKumar : delimeter can be different for a csv file. you only have add a delimeter class, provided csv file is generated via script.

Comment: @AjayGupta Why is that comment pointed to me?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: cz you are saying that csv file can have ',' as delimeter

Comment: No, I am saying he is using `,` delimiter to read the files and there is a line in a file that does not have that delimiter at all , and that is why `row[1]` is failing for the OP.

Comment: @Roujri You will also need to show us the code for `list_csv_all_files()` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar, that is the all code of `list_csv_all_files` and I tried with the sample that I posted here

Comment: Your function is called - `csv_all_files()` - and you are calling `list_csv_all_files()` - how is that working?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thats a mistake I changed it now

Answer (score 1):

You are having a problem whilst iterating through all of the files because some of the files have lines which do not contain your expected number of columns.

The process you are performing on them would also mean that after running your script once, all of the files would fail should you run the script a second time.

I suggest modifying the script as follows. It tests that each line has the correct number of columns. If the number is incorrect it aborts writing to `temp_file` and lets you know which line number it failed on and continues with the remaining files.

Also, you would need to carry out your rename outside of the `with` otherwise the file would still be open.

The end result of running the script would be that you are left will temp files where the conversion was aborted. These could then be manually fixed and the script restarted. Afterwards you could then delete all the `_temp_` files.

So based on your original question's code:

```
import os, csv

def csv_all_files():
    folder = "mystartfolder"

    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        endaddress = item
        if endaddress.endswith(".csv"):
            print endaddress
            input_file = os.path.join(folder,item)
            temp_file = os.path.join(folder, item + "_temp_")
            ok = True

            with open(input_file, 'r') as f_input, open(temp_file, 'w') as f_output:
                reader = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=',')
                for line_number, row in enumerate(reader):
                    if len(row) == 3:
                        f_output.write('"{}" {} "{}"\n'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
                    else:
                        print "{} line {} is badly formatted".format(input_file, line_number+1)
                        ok = False
                        break

            if ok:
                os.rename(temp_file, input_file)

csv_all_files()
```

By doing it this way, the output will show you where any problematic CSV files are.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a rod for your own back by renaming the amended files back to the originals for a start and you are never writing to the output either.
Try this:

```
#def list_csv_files(csv_folder):
import os, csv
input_file_list = []
cwd = os.getcwd()
input_file_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cwd):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".csv"):
            print name
            input_file_list.append(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, name)))
            print input_file_list
for input_file in input_file_list:
    temp_file = "./temp.out"
    f = open(input_file, 'rb')
    fo = open(temp_file, 'w')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        one = '"'+ row[0] + '"'
        two = row[1]
        three = '"'+ row[2] +'"'
        fo.write(one+" "+two+" "+three+"\n")
    f.close()
    fo.close()
    os.rename(temp_file, input_file)
```